# CRYPTO write after end

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I have a function that ciphers a password. For this, I am using nodejs crypto module.

To test, I just copy/paste the code given the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher)

```
static cipherPassword(password, cb) {

    let encrypted = '';
    cipher.on('readable', () => {
      const data = cipher.read();
      if (data)
        encrypted += data.toString('hex');
    });
    cipher.on('end', () => cb(encrypted));

    cipher.write(password);
    cipher.end();

}
```

I am encountering an error:

> events.js:183
>
> throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
>
> Error: write after end

I don't have solution to my problem. Could you help me please?

Thank you!

EDIT 1. As asked, here's a little piece of code to show how my static function is working.

My static function belongs to UserModel class

```
UserModel.cipherPassword('password to cipher', function(cipheredPassword) {
    // Do you whatever you wanna do with your ciphered password
});
```

Comment: *I just copy/paste the code* ... clearly you haven't ... there's no `static cipherPassword` in the link you posted

Comment: I am sorry, I just copied/pasted the code on the documentation, and I inserted in my static function @JaromandaX

Comment: Perhaps you could show in a minimal way how you use your function - my guess is, the error occurs the second time you call it - the function you've created can only be called once, unless you create a new cipher object before you call it each time

Comment: Oh yes! It does make sense! I am going to try!

Comment: It's working! @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JaromandaX,

I solved my problem.

Like he said, cipher object cannot be used twice. So I had to recreated it every time I was calling  my static function.

Thank you!

Comment: to be honest, having a global `cipher` object you have to create before calling the function isn't a "tidy" solution